# What is na4zi4pang2 (pinyin) in the decomposition of na4 (那)?

Tags: characters, pinyin

The [New Practical Chinese Reader](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/7561910401) introduces the following [decomposition](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/3501/how-does-cjk-decomposition-compare-to-the-wikimedia-commons-chinese-characters-d): na4 (那) = na4zi4pang2 + yi4 (阝).

I understand that 阝 represents [radical 163](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%98%9D) (yi4).

Na4zi4pang2 (pinyin) looks close to [radical 74](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E2%BD%89) (yue4, 月), but only close. It apparently is not a proper Chinese word or phrase that can be looked up in a dictionary.

My current guess that it is an arbitrary construct for a situation where one of the basic constituents of a composite character is not another basic character nor a radical, yet something that is also made up of strokes, and that the pinyin name is the concatenation of stroke names.

Could an expert and/or native speaker please confirm or otherwise clarify. I'm especially interested whether such constructs have Unicode font representations (and what the Unicode representation U+*xxxx* of na4zi4pang2 would then be).

Comment: Na4zi4pang2 is Pinyin for '那字旁', literally 'the radical from 那'. I don't think there is a Unicode character for this radical.

Comment: @NS.X. You have a Unicode for nearly all characters (depends on the version).

Comment: @susisstrolch But that radical is not a character. It would be great if there is a Unicode character for it.

Comment: @NS.X. +1 I see. The verbatim translation of the pinyin really helped here. What I'm taking away from your comment (BTW, if you want to post it as answer, I would be inclined to accept it as the answer) also is that the term radical need not refer to the 214 radicals from the Kangxi dictionary alone.

Comment: I did as you suggested, to provide an answer that strictly speaks to the question. You've already got all the information you needed from the comments and @Stan's answer, but precision questioning and answering is a good thing to maintain for Q/A sites:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(This answer strictly speaks to the question. There is also some good, related information in the other answers you may find interesting.)

`Na4zi4pang2` is Pinyin for `那字旁`, literally 'the radical from 那'. It's the name of the radical instead of pronunciation for a character.

I am not an expert in character classification and (de)composition, I don't know in linguistics whether radicals are prescribed or can be defined by usage, hence I am unable to tell you whether the left side of `那` is indeed a radical, is not a radical because Kangxi Dictionary didn't list it, or is not a radical because of some deeper logic.

But we can be sure that it is not a character, and I don't think there is a Unicode character for it.

Comment: [](http://www.zdic.net/z/a6/kx/2867B.htm) or [](http://www.zdic.net/z/a6/kx/28697.htm) is the origin of `那`. Why not consider 冄 as `那字旁`?

Comment: @Stan Because I couldn't find any reference to support that, and I don't possess the expert knowledge to disambiguate when there is neither reference for it nor against it.

Comment: +1 and BTW I've also upvoted @Stan's very informed answer.

Comment: @NS.X. I think 說文解字's statement "从邑，冄聲" has clearly pointed out the radical and the phonetic part of 那 XD

Comment: @Stan Exactly because 冄 is (was) a standalone character, it would have been called 冄字旁, like all the other radicals that are also characters. The name 那字旁 implies it is referring to a non-character component.

Comment: @NS.X. I doubt it is because the author of *New Practical Chinese Reader: Textbook* is lazy to introduce the origin of 那 and then simply call the left part of 那 `那字旁`. Anyway, a beginner doesn't need to know the details.

Answer (score 7):

There is ***no*** [image: 那字旁] radical, but the left part of 那 can be

> ## 冄 rǎn (the same as 冉)
>
> U+5184
>
> #### Seal Script
>
> [image]

That's because in the seal script, 那 is written as

> [image]
>
> The left part is 冄, and the right part (radical) is 邑. So in 說文解字, it is described as
>
> > 从邑，冄聲。

But it is better not to call 冄 a "radical", because modern dictionaries and older dictionaries haven't listed it as a radical.

It is interesting in 康熙字典, 那 has these interchangeable characters:

> [image] [image]

But they are obsolete now, you should not use them.

Answer (score 4):

**The component is 「冄」, which is now written as 「冉」.** The relevant Unicode codepoints are:

- 「冄」, reconstructed full character, U+5184
- 「冉」, modern character, U+5189
- 「  」, left hand component of「那」, [U+2D0C2](http://en.glyphwiki.org/wiki/u2d0c2) ([CJK Unified Ideographs Extension F](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Unified_Ideographs_Extension_F); unlikely to be displayed on most computers). [Ideographic description sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_character_description_language#Ideographic_Description_Sequences) record this component as「⿻二刀」.

---

「那」 ([Baxter-Sagart OC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconstructions_of_Old_Chinese#Baxter%E2%80%93Sagart_(2014)): **/*nˤar/**), originally referring to the [State of Na](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Na_(Chinese_state)), is comprised of phonetic 「冄」 (**/*nam/**) and semantic 「邑・阝」 (*town*, *city*). The meaning *that* is a late derivative of 「若」 (as according to Schuessler; Baxter-Sagart OC: **/*nak/**), and uses 「那」 as a phonetic loan.

> For reference, the shapes of「那」are recorded as the following:
>
> <kbd>[篆](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_seal_script)
> [image]
> [邑部](https://ctext.org/library.pl?if=gb&file=77390&page=89)
> [說文解字](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuowen_Jiezi)</kbd><kbd>今
> [楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script)
> [image]</kbd>

「冄」 depicts *loose-hanging, soft feathers*:

<kbd>[西周](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Zhou)
[金](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_bronze_inscriptions)
[image]
師㝨簋
[集成4313](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=4313&jgwfl=)</kbd>
<kbd>篆
[image]
[冄部](https://ctext.org/library.pl?if=gb&file=77391&page=59)
說文解字</kbd>
<kbd>[隸定](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hk/%E9%9A%B6%E5%AE%9A)
[image]</kbd>

Clerical script styles later added a vertical stroke, leading on to the modern shape.

<kbd>[東漢](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_han)
[隸](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clerical_script)
[image]
鄭固碑</kbd>
　<kbd>今
楷
[image]</kbd>

The original meaning of the character is now written as 「髯」 (*beard*/*moustache*). The word [「冉冉」](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%86%89%E5%86%89) (*slowly*/*loose hanging*) is an extension of the original meaning.

---

## References:

- 季旭昇《說文新證》
- 李學勤《字源》
- [中華語文知識庫・漢字源流](http://chinese-linguipedia.org/search_source.html)
- [小學堂](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/)
- [國學大師](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/)

Answer (score -2):

If you use the too [native2ascii](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/native2ascii.html)  you can convert any character / text to its ASCII representation.

Applied to 那字旁 阝you get \u90a3\u5b57\u65c1 \u961d

Comment: Now what does this show? So `native2ascii` can go from font characters to Unicode code points? The question is concerned with interpreting a bitmap. If I consult the [Unihan database](http://www.unicode.org/charts/unihan.html) I can go both ways between characters and code points but still not start from a bitmap. BTW, if I apply Chinese OCR to na4zi4pang2, it fails.