# What character is 刄 + 丶?

Tags: characters

Here's a pic I took in HK today

[image: 1]

What's the 刄 + 丶 char? In

> 堂飲2 xxxxxxx 28元

I'm guessing its similar to mainlands 两, for alcoholic drink sizes.

I tried zisea & zdic to no avail...

edit: is it this: ? http://www.zdic.net/z/84/wy/20090.htm
It's the closest thing I can find

Comment: The description "刄 + 点" had me totally baffled. But the unusual character still stood out enough (-:

Comment: I want to forge such characters, they never be used anymore, only few of elder people still use them, they are not standardized glyph.

Comment: Although the character is totally unrelated to 「那」, it appears to be the same as the left hand side of 「那」. See https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/3889/18338

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it is indeed a variant of 两. You can see it listed here in the *Dictionary of Chinese Character Variants* 《異體字字典》:

http://dict2.variants.moe.edu.tw/variants/rbt/word_attribute.rbt?educode=A00284

[image: A00284]

As for why they've chosen to write it this way, I'm not sure.

Comment: Is this Unicode?

Comment: I couldn't find it in Unicode.

Comment: I will note that it does look like the left-hand component of [那](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%82%A3), which is noted as being [冄](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%86%84), which is a variant of [冉](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%86%89). The similarity appears only to be superficial though and is unrelated to its usage as a variant of 两 though.

Comment: Zisea has it here: http://zisea.com/zscontent.asp?uni=181468 with no additional information at all

Comment: Now it is in Unicode:  (U+2D0C2, in Extension F).

Answer (score 0):

Like @Claw pointed out. This is the variant of 两.

Unlike Latin characters, Chinese characters are graph-like characters. So it's easy to create a brand new character to describe the same thing.

In the China history, Ordinary people could use whatever characters they want as long as they could identify them. Even though government introduced several dictionaries to standardized, there is no strict law to forbid using variants of character.